# Formula in Excel to count occurrences of substrings within strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of times a sub-string appears within a column of string data in Excel. Please see the below example.

The column of string data (tweets) looks like this:

```
   A
1  An example string with @username in it
2  RT @AwesomeUser says @username is awesome
```

The column with "substrings" (Twitter screen names) looks like this:

```
   B
1  username
2  AwesomeUser
```

I want to use a formula to count the number of times that a substring from B1, B2, etc. appears in the strings in column A. For example: a formula searching for B1 would return "2" and a search for B2 would return "1".

I can't do it this way:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "username")
```

because COUNTIF only looks for strings, not substrings. This formula would always return "0".

Here's a [formula](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/341605-solved-counting-the-number-of-times-a-word-appears-in-a-worksheet.html) I thought might do it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A:A)-(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"username",""))))/LEN("username"))
```

Unfortunately, I have 16,000 entries in column B and tens of thousands in A, so counting characters won't work even on a high power PC (also, the result returned by the function is suspect).

I thought about using:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "*username*")
```

but COUNTIF requires a string with the star operators; I need to use cell references due to the volume of data.

My question: does anyone know how I can use a formula for this? If using COUNTIF, how do I get a cell reference in the conditional part of the statement (or use a function to substitute the string in the cell referenced within the conditional part of a COUNTIF statement)?

I know that I *could* parse the data, but I would like to know how to do it in Excel.

Comment: Note that the SUMPRODUCT formula you quote does a slightly different thing to Chris' COUNTIF function. COUNTIF will only count each cell once at most, so each cell either "scores" 1 or zero. The SUMPRODUCT formula will count `ALL` instances or "username" even if it appears more than once in any individual cell - if you want to use that formula you should restrict the range rather than using the whole column

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are nearly there, use

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "*"&B1&"*")
```

Caveat:
This counts the number of cells in `A:A` that contain the string one *or more* times.  It does not count the *total* number of instances of the string.

Comment: Chris: That seems like the answer. Thanks for the assist! I tried concatenation last night but I must have screwed up the syntax.

Comment: CHRIS, this does not work. try the following: in b1 type "1", now a2:"s1df1, a3:"dsad", a4: "sd`1", a5: "sdf1111"

Comment: @Aртём Царионов tried your data, returns a count of 3.  What did you expect?

Comment: With LibreOffice:
`=COUNTIF(A:B, ".*"&C&".*")` :}

Comment: Argument seperator may be different at yours excel. If you get an error, you can try with use semicolon. example `=COUNTIF(A:A; "*"&B1&"*")`

Answer (score 5):

**A very Simple Excel Solution for occurrence of x-string ("ABC") into y-string ("ABC 123 ABC 23dfABC"):**

1. Identify length of y-string. Ly = len(y)
2. Substitute x-string by x1-string (append only 1 char of any supported character to x-string. e.g. "ABC"=> "ABC_" ) and calculate length of new string y1-string. Ly1 = len(substitute(y,x,x1)).
3. No of occurrence of x-string) in y-string = Ly1-Ly

Number of Occurrence: len(substitute(y,x,x1)) - len(y)

**Nomenclature for Understanding:**
x-string: "ABC"
x1-string: "ABC_"
y-string: "ABC 123 ABC 23dfABC"
y1-string: ""ABC_ 123 ABC_ 23dfABC_"

Comment: OP asked for occurrence count in a full column of cells. This answer counts occurrences in a single cell (or single string)... which was actually exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!!! :-D.

Comment: Thank you Vinod. Very elegant solution to my problem. Indeed counting the number of occurrences of a substring within a string.

Answer (score 1):

**Finding actual occurrencies via `TEXTJOIN` function**

Using `TEXTJOIN` (available since version 2019 or MS 365) allows to get the *actual* number of any occurrencies in one or more columns (column `A:A` or e.g. even columns `A:B`).

Thus it **avoids** the *Caveat* of the `COUNTIF` function

> *"to count only the number of cells (in A:A) that contain the string one or more times. It does not count the total number of instances of the string."*

**Three Methodical steps**

The formula shown (assuming a named search term `MySearch`) below executes only three logical steps to get the actual number of findings:

- `1` join all filled cells in given column(s) via `TEXTJOIN`,
- `2` replace the search terms in string `1` with a term length reduced by minus 1 and
- `3` subtract the length of string `2` from length of string `1`.

```
=LEN(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,A:B))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,A:B),MySearch,LEFT(MySearch,LEN(MySearch)-1)))
```

MS Help [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)