# Sum of values associated with a string when a single cell contains multiple strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To simplify the screening of candidates for a college program, we created an Excel sheet compiling information provided by candidates.

They had to select one or more academic achievements from a droplist (some have none, some have 25).
The result in the Excel file is a cell for each student/row where the achievements are separated by line breaks.

We have a table where each of the possible achievement is worth a certain number of points.
For instance, a master's degree is worth 4, a published article is worth 2, etc.

**We want to add a column that states the number of points a candidate has based on the cell that contains one or more achievements.**

How can we do that with Excel?

Thank you!

[Table with weighted value of achievement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsbMa.png)
[image]

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Pr1.png)

[image]

Ideally, some students have multiple occurrences of an achievement and we would want to take it into account (for instance, published two articles = 6 points) but that's a nice-to-have.

As of now, I have tried:

- Combining SUM and VLOOKUP function, but I can only seem to recognize one value per cell
- Experimenting with the SUMIF function, but that did not seem to work for me
- Experimenting with nested conditions
- Adapting solutions that require multiple criteria in multiple cell (for instance, return price if the row contains *dress* and *blue*, but none seem to apply for the situation when there are multiple strings in a single cell.

Comment: Visitors are discouraged to come to this forum asking for free code. Therefore there is a rule that requires an "own effort", an effort on the part of the asker to solve the problem himself. Your problem requires code. There is no "own effort" included in your question. I vote to close for non-compliance with forum rules. You can still edit your question and show what you have tried.

Comment: That's a great rule! I just added to my posts the functions I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` works but you have use an array for `lookup_value` consisting of each achievement.  Since the achievements are from a drop-down, we can assume they are spelled correctly.

We can use `FILTERXML` to split the entry by the line-feeds into an array of separate nodes, and then use that to find the appropriate values.

*`FILTERXML` is in Windows Excel 2013+ but not available in Excel for MAC or online. If necessary, I can supply a different function to do the splitting.*

For example:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP( FILTERXML("<t><s>"& SUBSTITUTE(E2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),AchieveTbl,2,FALSE))
```

**AchieveTbl**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `=SUM((LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,$A$2:$A$8,$A$2:$A$8&"_"))-LEN(E2))*$B$2:$B$8)`

This is based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948338/formula-in-excel-to-count-occurrences-of-substrings-within-strings)